# How do I highlight certain words between double quotes with font-lock?

Tags: font-lock, regular-expressions, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to add additional colors to json-mode for when I edit json-schema.  I can get it working fine without searching for double quotes, but I need to for some highlighting.  I've tried quite a few things to highlight *properties* inside of "properties" including:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'json-mode '(("""\\(properties\\)""" 1 '(:foreground "chartreuse4") t))
(font-lock-add-keywords 'json-mode '(("\\""\\(properties\\)"\\"" 1 '(:foreground "chartreuse4") t))
(font-lock-add-keywords 'json-mode '(("\\s""\\(properties\\)\\s""" 1 '(:foreground "chartreuse4") t))
```

I expect once I understand the solution, I can easily highlight *object* in "type": "object" which was my original goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put a `"` char inside a string in Lisp, just put one backslash in front of it.

If you want to highlight anything (not just `properties`) between double-quotes, try this as your regexp:

```el
"\"\\(?:[^\"]\\|\\\\\\(?:.\\|[\n]\\)\\)*\""
```

That assumes that a backslash escapes any char - in particular the char `"`, so that `\"` is highlighted inside the string. Similarly for backslash preceding any other char. Dunno whether you want that, but you get the idea.