# Automatically highlight elements in an XML buffer

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, highlighting, nxml

I spend a lot of time in XML buffers using nxml-mode (Emacs 26). Out of hundreds of XML elements, I am only interested in one or two. How can I have Emacs always show the XML elements I'm interested in with a different colour? This will help me keep track of the important elements while working without having to keep searching with `C-s` and `C-r`.

For example, in the following XML file, I want the tags for element `THING_NAME` to show up in a different coloured font instead of the default blue, and leave the tags for elemenst `XML_FILE`, `THING_VERSION`, and `THING_TYPE` in the default colour.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-'?>
<XML_FILE>
  <THING_VERSION>2.2</THING_VERSION>
  <THING_NAME>BOB</THING_NAME>
  <THING_TYPE>ITEM</THING_TYPE>
</XML_FILE>
```

Here's a screenshot. It would be great if the highlighted tags for `THING_NAME` were in a different colour, like pink or red, to make it easier to see in large files.

[[image: THING_NAME element should be a different colour[1]]

I've tried adding [`font-lock-add-keywords`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/6118) to init.el but it had no effect. For example:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'nxml-mode
        '(("THING_NAME" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

I also tried adding a hook to the mode using [`add-hook`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html) from the Emacs manual:

```
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook
         (lambda ()
          (font-lock-add-keywords nil
           '(("\\(THING_NAME\\)" 1
              font-lock-warning-face t)))))
```

After reading the nxml-mode [Emacs documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/nxml-mode.html) and [Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NxmlMode) entries, and installing themes from MELPA and looking at the code, I'm still unsure of how to proceed.

This has been driving me crazy! Any help would be very appreciated, and I'm sure many others would find this useful. Maybe I am approaching this the wrong way. Would it be better to have an always-on search that permanently highlighted specific matches?

---

**Solution after the response from `glucas`, shown below**

Thanks to `glucas` I created a regexp [interactive highlight](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Highlight-Interactively.html#Highlight-Interactively) for "THING_NAME". The keys I typed were:

```
 M-s h r   THING_NAME   RET   RET
```

I extended this to good final solution by creating a [keyboard macro](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) to automatically bind `C-c t` to the interactive highlight in ~/.emacs.d/init.el. The macro is named `thingname`, so I can also type `M-x thingname`. Notice how the regexp search term "THING_NAME" is escaped as "?T ?H ?I ?N ?G ?_ ?N ?A ?M ?E":

```
(fset 'thingname
  [?\M-s ?h ?r ?T ?H ?I ?N ?G ?_ ?N ?A ?M ?E return return])
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") 'thingname)
```

Applied to the example XML above, it looks like this:

[image]

You can add multiple highlights, each with a different colour, by repeating the call to M-s h r as many times as needed. Here, I add another highlight for "THING_WEIGHT" to the same binding:

```
(fset 'thingname
  [?\M-s ?h ?r ?T ?H ?I ?N ?G ?_ ?N ?A ?M ?E return return
   ?\M-s ?h ?r ?T ?H ?I ?N ?G ?_ ?W ?E ?I ?G ?H ?T return return])
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") 'thingname)
```

[image]

Comment: You could also create a function rather than a keyboard macro. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs provides a general-purpose highlight mechanism which might work here. See [Interactive Highlighting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Highlight-Interactively.html#Highlight-Interactively) in the Emacs manual.

The relevant commands are `highlight-phrase` or `highlight-regexp` to define what you want to highlight (and in what color). You can ask Hi Lock mode to save the highlight instructions in the file itself using `hi-lock-write-interactive-patterns`. That gives you a flexible way to define and persist highlight instructions without writing any Elisp.

Alternatively you can define you own functions to set up highlighting with the same commands, and hook them to nxml mode. That would be a better approach if you want 
the same highlight rules across many files and/or cannot add comments to the files.

For example:

```
(defun my-xml-highlights ()
  (interactive)
  (highlight-phrase "THING_NAME" 'hi-yellow)
  (highlight-phrase "THING_WEIGHT" 'hi-pink))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") 'my-xml-highlights)
```